# socket.io-Difference between emit functions

Tags: socket.io

I am a newby in socket.io and i really wonder like in this code example what is socket.emit and io.emit exactly doing? What is the difference of them? Thanks in advance

```
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connection', function(socket){

socket.emit('asd', data);
io.emit('das', data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `socket` is one connection to one user, whereas `io` is global so will send to everyone.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer sir saved me a lot of time

Comment: John, I am looking for the same answer too. Can you please provide me where i can find more information on the same.